# How can I retrieve the auto increment number from the related thread's row on "threads" table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table for "threads" and a table for "comments" on my database. Both tables have an auto increment ID column, timestamp etc. There is also a "THREAD ID" column where I'd like to INSERT thread's IDs in the "comments" table.

My question is: how can I retrieve the auto increment ID number of the related thread's row from "threads" table and INSERT this number to the "comments" table's "THREAD ID" column every time when I insert a comment. So I can create a link between "comments" and "threads".

I'm somewhat beginner at PHP and I'd like to learn with the explanation of the code. Like which string is for what, which method is for what..

```
<?php
/*show error codes*/
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off
/* database info*/
define('DB_NAME', 'imageboard');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link1 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link1) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link1, DB_NAME);


if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}
//when pressed submit
if (isset($_POST['replySubmit'])) {
//buton ve textarea def
$deger = $_POST ['replyComments'];
$deger2 = $_POST ['replyNickName'];
$deger3 = $_FILES ['replyUserFile']['name'];
// WANT TO DEFINE THREAD ID HERE
//deger4 = $_POST [];
// SEND TO DATABASE
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO newReply (COMMENT, NAME, IMAGENAME) VALUES ('$deger', '$deger2', '$deger3')";
//connection check
if (!mysqli_query($link1, $sql1)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
} else {
    header('Location: ./thread.php');
}
}
?>
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['replyUserFile'])) {
$uploadName1 = $_FILES['replyUserFile']['name'];
$uploadTmp1 = $_FILES['replyUserFile']['tmp_name'];
$uploadType1 = $_FILES['replyUserFile']['type'];

// CORRECTION
$uploadName1 = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.,]#i", "_", $uploadName1);
// FILES TO directory
if(!$uploadTmp1) {
    die("can't send...");
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($uploadTmp1, "./images/$uploadName1");
}

$link1 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link1) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected1 = mysqli_select_db($link1, DB_NAME);


if (!$db_selected1) {
    die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}
//INSERT INTO tables
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO images (USERIMAGENAME) VALUES ('$uploadName1')";
//connection check
if (!mysqli_query($link1, $sql1)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
} else {
// CHANGE THE NAME OF THE IMAGE FILE IN THE DIRECTORY TO DATABASE ID NUMBER
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link1);
    $ext1 = pathinfo("./images/$uploadName1", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    rename("./images/$uploadName1", "./images/$last_id".".".$ext1);
    // GO BACK TO THREAD
    header('Location: ./thread.php');
}
}
mysqli_close($link1);
?>
```

[image: 2 tables]

Comment: `My SQL` or `SQL SERVER` ??

Comment: Do you have any PHP code for Comment insertion? If yes, post it here.

Comment: will add the comment insertion code to the question in a min

Comment: Are you creating the thread and the comment at the same time? You don't seem to be having a thread_id by the time you insert the comment. I think you will rather have to pass it as a parameter to this script and use it in your query.

Comment: You can use the methods shown in the answers below if you create the thread before you insert the comment. But I don't think you are creating the thread at that time, right? so what you want to do is, when you submit the comment form, pass thread_id too as a parameter, then use it in your query.

Comment: @ user3571366 yes I want to use it to sort only the related comments under each topic. threads and comments created separately and at different times.

Comment: Then you can't use the mysqli_insert_id() to get the thread_id because it's something you've created earlier. What you have to do is include the thread_id as a hidden field (maybe) in your comment form and pass it to the submit page, there you can get the id and use in your comments query. Hope you got my point.

Comment: is sending hidden field values secure way to do this?

Comment: That's why I said this is just a rough idea :) But I don't see any wrong when it comes to security, as a 'thread_id' is not something to be treated confidentially :) but of course your users can cheat on you by changing the thread_id in the field. So you can use some mechanism to validate the thread_id to see if it's a valid id or not. It's fine as long as the thread_id is valid. You may want to use sessions if you really worry about this.

Comment: I guess I'll see how this will work out first. then I'll search what to look out for when using hidden fields.

I guess I couldn't explain myself clear enough for others to understand that's why they offered that solution. anyway..

Comment: It was your title which mislead them :) They haven't actually checked the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering why others suggest you to use mysqli_insert_id() when you want to get the thread_id. As I know, mysqli_insert_id() will return you the successfully inserted id of the last mysql query.

But here, when I check your code, you are not creating the thread here. It's something that has been already created (earlier).

What you trying to accomplish is (As I understand), you want to store the 'thread_id' in your 'comment' table as a reference to which thread this comment was posted, right?

My suggestion is to use a hidden field in your comment form and pass the thread_id to the submit page.

Then you can retrieve 'thread_id' too, in the same way you get the replyNickname, replyComment etc.

And then, use that 'thread_id' inside your query.

Ex:

```
//when pressed submit
if (isset($_POST['replySubmit'])) {
//buton ve textarea def
$deger = $_POST ['replyComments'];
$deger2 = $_POST ['replyNickName'];
$deger3 = $_FILES ['replyUserFile']['name'];
// WANT TO DEFINE THREAD ID HERE
$thread_id = $_POST ['thread_id']; // Note this line

//deger4 = $_POST [];
// SEND TO DATABASE
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO newReply (COMMENT, NAME, IMAGENAME, THREAD_ID) VALUES ('$deger', '$deger2', '$deger3', '$thread_id')";
//connection check
if (!mysqli_query($link1, $sql1)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
} else {
    header('Location: ./thread.php');
}
}
```

I hope what I understood is right. This is just a rough idea, you can pass the thread_id in anyway you want. But I don't see any point of using mysqli_insert_id() here.

Comment: exactly what I was trying to do and I guess I'll have to use a hidden field. thank you for your answer. I'll up vote this when I reach 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

```
//If the previous request triggered an auto increment
if (mysqli_insert_id($link)<>'') {

    //retrieves the last ID
    $lastID = mysqli_insert_id($link);

    //do something
    }
else {
    //do something else...

}
```

Be sure that you chose INNODB engine in order to be able to handle foreign keys

Comment: can you provide us the structure of your tables in proper SQL form please ? As you explained it, the "column" thread ID in your Comments table sounds like a foreign key. Does it ? But show us the structure of your DB please, it will help

Comment: I want to retrieve data from older rows too, will this work only for the last entry or it works for the previous entries too?

Comment: you said you wanted to retrieve the thread ID evey time you added a new comment, so the solution in this case is to do as explained above. If you want to retrieve older data, a SELECT with proper parameters will do the trick. But once again, I can't tell more without having seen your database, or at least the two tables you mention

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me explain with another example : I have a Clients table, and an Order table. An order can only be made by one client, whereas a client can make several orders. So, in the Orders table, I must store the ID of the client who made the order. It is a bad idea to store this ID as a "normal" field, beacuse it is strongly linked to the Clients table. Such an attribute is named a foreign key. In order to solve your problem, you'd better think about the structure of your DB...it must be as "consistent" as possible. Hope it helps

Comment: oh now it makes sense  : ) thank you I'll search on this and try to use this first.

Comment: you're welcome. once you have a clean DB structure, you'll see that it will be easier to work with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL:

PDO (where $pdoConn is your PDO connection):

```
$yourlastID = $pdoConn->lastInsertId();
```

mysqli:

```
$yourlastID = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL, use SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertIntoThreads]
(
@THREAD_ID int OUTPUT,
@Column1 varchar(50) = NULL,
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert Into Threads(Column1) 
    values(@Column1);
SET @THREAD_ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Hope it helps. :)